# Change entire window view in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, frame

I have a main window that I created and it looks like usual log in screen.

Once the user click on a button I would like the whole window to change.

In all the examples I saw either I have to keep a stackpanel/dock and then only the frame changes.

For example, I have the following Main window xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="Main" Margin="0,35,0,0"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,105,326,100"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the new page:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.Optimizer"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="Optimizer">
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="91" Margin="125,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="129"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And my command is:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Content = new Optimizer();
    }
```

In that case the two views appear on same page instead of switching completely.

Its not the case im looking for. I need the whole window to change and not leave behind a stackpanel.

Any simple example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First thing to mention here is that pages and frames are rarely used by commercial teams. At least not in my experience.
Unless writing xbap - which is wpf in a browser.

I suggest you consider usercontrols rather than pages and host them in contentcontrols.
You can then have something like:

```
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Click handler:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = new UserControl1();
    }
```

That makes the entire content of mainwindow an instance of UserControl1.
A Window inherits from contentcontrol.

You should also have learning mvvm on your list.
You should learn that.  Maybe not right now, but soon.